# Emails does not save in Sent folder when using SMTP

Tags: smtp, apache-commons-email

I'm using Apache Commons Email in user application for mailing purposes. Letters sends succusfully and client recieves it. The problem is sent emails does not save in Sent folder on server. My code:

```
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.ukr.net");
email.setSmtpPort(2525);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("****@ukr.net", "****"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
```

Is it the problem of email smtp provider or problem of my code?